# Animate ImageView to revel hidden portion due to centerCrop

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-animation

Here is my simple Layout

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"                            
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"                
            />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I want to apply scale animation on Layout/ImageView (I don't know on which?) to reveal hidden part of Image which are cropped due to scaleType centerCrop.

I have tried simple scale animation but it stretches the image itself.

Comment: animate the matrix m, Matrix m = iv.getImageMatrix()

Comment: Thanks for this. I would appreciate if you can give me more detail that what exactly you are trying to do here. This will help me to understand it fundamentally.

Answer (score 0):

try this custom Animation:

```
class MatrixAnimation extends Animation {
    private float[][] v = new float[3][9];
    private ImageView target;

    public MatrixAnimation(ImageView target, Matrix m0, Matrix m1) {
        this.target = target;
        m0.getValues(v[0]);
        m1.getValues(v[1]);
        setDuration(2000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        Matrix m = target.getImageMatrix();
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            v[2][i] = v[0][i] + (v[1][i] - v[0][i]) * interpolatedTime;
        }
        m.setValues(v[2]);
        target.setImageMatrix(m);
    }
}
```

starting code:

```
    final ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.layer0);
    iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    LayoutParams p = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200);
    setContentView(iv, p);

    OnClickListener l = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Matrix m0 = iv.getImageMatrix();
            Matrix m1 = new Matrix();
            Drawable d = iv.getDrawable();
            RectF src = new RectF(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
            RectF dst = new RectF(0, 0, iv.getWidth(), iv.getHeight());
            m1.setRectToRect(src, dst, ScaleToFit.CENTER);

            iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

            MatrixAnimation anim = new MatrixAnimation(iv, m0, m1);
            iv.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    };
    iv.setOnClickListener(l);
```

Comment: thanks for this. Let me try this and will update you.

Comment: @user2095470 and is it what you wanted?

Comment: I am not sure what will be the output of this..I can only tell you after implementing it.